# Ubuntu cronjob fails to run after first run

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, csv, cron

I'm currently running this script in a cronjob every thirty minutes or so:

```
*/30 * * * * wget "http://mydomain.com?import_key=acxmlK&import_id=1&action=processing"
```

It's a script used to import posts to Wordpress from CSV files. For some reason, cronjobs that import files with less than 2000 rows work fine. But if the cronjob hits a file with more than 2000 rows, it doesn't run.

I have no idea what's going on because I don't have a way to diagnose if the job has run or not, nor can I see where the error is going on.

Does anybody have any idea why does files with less than 2000 rows finish the cronjob but above that, the cronjob doesn't run.

Alternatively any way to diagnose the error or see if the cronjob is running is also helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Does it work as expected when you run `wget "http://mydomain.com?import_key=acxmlK&import_id=1&action=processing"` manually?

Comment: Well it works the first time, I manually run the command and all posts in that file will be imported. But if I manually run it again, then it would be "run" on the system level but from the wordpress control panel, I'm seeing that the posts remain the same